# Cannot access API on Postman or Browser by running docker container on Port 8080

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, .net-6.0

I have a simple API which I am running in Docker

When I run the command to run my image I get the output below

```
PS C:\Users\harili\GoodFood-backend> docker run -p 8080:80 --name container-backend-goodfood image-backend-goodfood
{"EventId":60,"LogLevel":"Warning","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository","Message":"Storing keys in a directory \u0027/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys\u0027 that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.","State":{"Message":"Storing keys in a directory \u0027/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys\u0027 that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.","path":"/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys","{OriginalFormat}":"Storing keys in a directory \u0027{path}\u0027 that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed."}}
{"EventId":35,"LogLevel":"Warning","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager","Message":"No XML encryptor configured. Key {f3c716ee-bcbe-4357-ba6e-3fcdbb6b9817} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.","State":{"Message":"No XML encryptor configured. Key {f3c716ee-bcbe-4357-ba6e-3fcdbb6b9817} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.","KeyId":"f3c716ee-bcbe-4357-ba6e-3fcdbb6b9817","{OriginalFormat}":"No XML encryptor configured. Key {KeyId:B} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form."}}
{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","State":{"Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","{OriginalFormat}":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down."}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Hosting environment: Production","State":{"Message":"Hosting environment: Production","envName":"Production","{OriginalFormat}":"Hosting environment: {envName}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Content root path: /app","State":{"Message":"Content root path: /app","contentRoot":"/app","{OriginalFormat}":"Content root path: {contentRoot}"}}
```

However, I get connection refused when using Postman (even on browser)

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/Authentication/test (it's a get http request)

```
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok(new { Test = "it works test"});
        }
```

Any idea what is wrong?

My docker file is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GoodFood.Api/GoodFood.Api.csproj", "GoodFood.Api/"]
COPY ["GoodFood.Library/GoodFood.Library.csproj", "GoodFood.Library/"]
RUN dotnet restore "GoodFood.Api/GoodFood.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/GoodFood.Api"
RUN dotnet build "GoodFood.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GoodFood.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GoodFood.Api.dll"]
```

As you can see I am exposing port 80 above

There the command I use to run my container :

```
docker run -p 8080:80 --name container-backend image-backend
```

Comment: You have 2 versions of the `docker run` command in your post. The one in the bottom maps to port 8080 on the host and the one above the log maps to port 80. Are you sure you've mapped to 8080 when testing?

Comment: Most probably you have middleware `UseHttpsRedirection` in your app but the https (443) port is not exposed and mapped.

Comment: @HansKilian Ops that was the old command line, I corrected that. And yes, I've clearly mapped to 8080 but nothing happens

Comment: Can you add the routing bit of your controller to the post, to make sure that the route exists?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yes I do have a middleware. Why it should occurs problem ? And why https(443) should be mapped ?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan In the log it only says that it's listening on port 80, so it doesn't look like it wants to use https.

Comment: @HansKilian I added the endpoint as you asked

Comment: Do you have some Swagger code in Program.cs? If so, can you try adding `ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` in the 'final' section in the Dockerfile. Then build and run the image. And then try going to `http://localhost:8080/swagger`. Does that work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239562/discussion-between-harili-and-hans-kilian).